# Cloud Foundry Basic Questions

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am very new to Cloud Foundry/Bosh and have a set of basic questions.

**1) Droplet vs Garden container:** I understand that droplet contains source code + build pack and these droplets are executed in garden container.  IMHO, containers are good to transport to other system. Why there is intermediate notion of droplets? Should container by them-self not  create the droplets?

**2) Diego cell:** What is the role of Diego cell (I assume that its job is to only start/stop garden containers) ? Are Diego cell platform dependent (eg. particular cell can run only windows-garden or other can run linux-garden container) ? Do we need one  cell per container?

3) In the description of Diego cell, I read "**Each application VM has a Diego Cell that executes application start and stop actions locally, manages the VM’s containers, and reports app status and other data to the BBS and Loggregator.**"
What is application VM mentioned here? Does it mean container?

4) Lets assume, I use Bosh to create my cloud foundry instance. After some time, I need to scale my system to two VMs (due to increase in load). Do I need to create a new Manifest for second VM (As the earlier manifest will also deploy the entire CF on this VM also)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A **container** is, roughly speaking, a root file system image together with some things like resource limits and metadata about what volumes to mount, what processes to run, etc.

**Garden** is an API for creating and running container specifications.  Anyone can write a server that implements the Garden API, the core Cloud Foundry teams maintain **garden-linux**, **garden-runC**, and **garden-windows** implementations.

A **droplet** is a "built" artifact created from source code that is typically mounted or streamed into a Garden container and then run.  There are times where you do not want a separate droplet, and want to have your root file system as well as all source code and/or built artifacts baked into a single image.  However, often, you *do* want this separation between the droplet, which represents your code, and the root file system.  One major benefit is that CVEs present in lower level dependencies that are common to most containers can be uniformly repaired across all tenants and all running applications on the Cloud Foundry platform without any developers having to re-push their code.  E.g. if there is a new patch required for something like `openssl`, and your Cloud Foundry installation has thousands of developers and hundreds of thousands of running Garden containers, it would be much better if an operator could roll out the `openssl` patch to all containers with a single command.

The **Diego cell** is a VM that's part of the Cloud Foundry architecture.  Cloud Foundry itself is a distributed system with different components responsible for different things.  There is a component responsible for user authorization and authentication, there are components for aggregating logs from applications, there is a component responsible for providing the developer-facing API for creating, scaling, and managing applications, etc.  The Diego cell's are responsible for essentially taking requests to run containerized workloads, and running them.  User requests to run an application are consumed by the user-facing API, and translated to a request to the Diego backend.  Diego itself has several components, including a scheduler, and the scheduler's job is to select which cell to do a given piece of work.

You can think of the cell has having two components: (1) a Garden server for running containers, and (2) a **representative** that can represent that Garden server to the Diego scheduler, so rather than Garden having any Diego-specific knowledge (Garden can function in a standalone manner), the scheduler instead talks to each Garden's Diego representative on that same cell.

I'm not sure what "application VM" means in the quote you pulled out.  Each application running on Cloud Foundry can be run with multiple parallel instances (for fault tolerance, better concurrency, etc.).  Each application instance is running as a Garden container in some Diego cell.  A production deployment of Cloud Foundry will have many Diego cells.  Each cell can run many (up to hundreds) of Garden containers.  For better fault tolerance, the Diego scheduler will attempt to place the instances of a given application on different Diego cells, rather than cramming them all into the same cell, since if that single cell goes down, your whole application goes down.

You do not need to create a new manifest to scale up BOSH deployments.  Just change the `instances` value of whatever job/instance group you want to have more VMs of, and re-run `bosh deploy`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I have few more questions: 1) Does Diego cell and VM have one to one cardinality (ie. given VM will have only one cell in it)? 2) What is the benefit of creating another abstraction Diego cell? Why can't Diego scheduler directly communicate with Garden container? Do Diego cell has some more function, which I am missing? 3) During Bosh scale up - Do all the VMs have all the CF components like Cloud Controller, CC Bridge, Diego etc. or Cloud Controller, CC Bridge will be only in one VM and others will have only Diego cells?

Comment: There are a few reasons, but the main one is that the "representative" process that is colocated with the Garden is responsible for communicating information about what the local Garden is running to the central Diego datastore.  Diego needs to maintain a central record of the state of what's actual running, so it can take corrective actions when, e.g. there are fewer actual containers running compare to what has been desired to run.  A cell is typically a VM running the representative + Garden.  There are typically other VMs for other purposes (e.g. Cloud Controller)...

Comment: ... BOSH allows you to scale up components individually.  You can scale up the Cloud Controllers separately, you can scale up the Cells separately, etc.  Also, having the Cloud Controller and Cells on separate VMs is just the most common deployment strategy.  You could, in principle, deploy all the components to a single VM.  Or you could deploy all the non-Cell components to a single VM, and the Cell as a different VM.  And then scale the Cell VMs up independently of the everything-else VMs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying further, still I have some follow up questions: 1) Can a single linux VM have multiple Diego cells running on it? 2) The representative running inside the Diego cell is one per cell or one per container?

Comment: 1. Yes, but seems like a waste.  2. Rep is one per cell, not one per container.  Cell = Rep + Garden.  Garden manages multiple containers.

Comment: Why it seems a waste? It should be more efficient, if VM is big enough it can run multiple Cells. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you gain from having multiple Cells in the VM instead of one Cell in the VM?

Comment: My point is, if the VM is capable of running multiple cell, we should run it.

Comment: No.  Your VM might also be capable of running 1000 minecraft servers, but why would you do it?

Answer (score 4):

1) The droplet is a container image that is stored persistently when you upload your application with a **cf push**. This image will be re-used whenever the system creates a new container with the same image (for example, when you restart your application, or scale to multiple instances). Without the droplet, you would have to re-upload your application and create the container image every time you wanted a new instance.

2) The Diego cell runs in a large VM that hosts many containers. A typical Diego cell might be 32G in size, while a typical container might be 1G. Diego cells currently only run Linux-Garden containers.

3) The application VM is just the VM that is hosting the Diego cell. I found the sentence a bit confusing because I tend to use the term Diego cell to refer both to the cell software and to the "application VM" which is hosting it.

4) Bosh will use multiple VMs to deploy Cloud Foundry. Single-VM deployments do exist (see for example, http://pivotal.io/pcf-dev) but they are not deployed with Bosh.

Comment: regarding 2) What is the use of Diego cell? Why containers cannot directly run on VMs? Does it mean that Every VM will have multiple Diego cell, which in turn will have multiple containers? regarding 4)  In multiple VMs to deploy CF, Does all the VMs have all the CloudFoundry components like Cloud Controller, CC Bridge, Diego etc. or Cloud Controller, CC Bridge will be only in one VM and others will have only Diego cells?

Comment: Further, regarding point 1) Can't we directly use something like `docker save` to save container image? Do we really need to maintain concept of droplet explicitly.